# Django Website Administration Broken

Tags: python, django

I have recently updated and the Django Website Administration has broken (I must add I do not know if that is the root cause of the problem as I have not used it for some time and have only just noticed it.

I get the following error:

```
Internal Server Error: /admin/

TemplateSyntaxError at /admin/
'future' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
account
account_tags
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
avatar_tags
cache
crispy_forms_field
crispy_forms_filters
crispy_forms_tags
crispy_forms_utils
dwadfilters
humanize
i18n
l10n
log
mathfilters
socialaccount
socialaccount_tags
static
staticfiles
tinymce_tags
tz
```

I have had a look round and some are suggesting it is a bug.  Some say to downgrade to 1.8 (which is not an option).  I will place the traceback at the bottom of this email.  Many thanks in advance for any help.

```
    Traceback:

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _legacy_get_response
  249.             response = self._get_response(request)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  217.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
  215.                 response = response.render()

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in render
  109.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py" in rendered_content
  86.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py" in render
  66.             return self.template.render(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  208.                     return self._render(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in _render
  199.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render
  994.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in render_annotated
  961.             return self.render(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in render
  152.         compiled_parent = self.get_parent(context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in get_parent
  149.         return self.find_template(parent, context)

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py" in find_template
  129.             template_name, skip=history,

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/engine.py" in find_template
  134.                         name, template_dirs=dirs, skip=skip,

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loaders/base.py" in get_template
  44.                     contents, origin, origin.template_name, self.engine,

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in __init__
  191.         self.nodelist = self.compile_nodelist()

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in compile_nodelist
  233.             return parser.parse()

File "/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py" in parse
  518.                     raise self.error(token, e)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost impossible to know for sure given what you've written but likely you upgraded past the point of a deprecated templatetags feature (`load ... from future`) and you need to go through and either upgrade the packages that have them or update your templates to no longer have the `from future` in the load tags.

Comment: Would you know where I start to search the templates?

Comment: I did notice __ future __ in the following file:/usr/share/str8RED-virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py

Comment: No, that's a separate Python thing. It shouldn't be inside of Django at all, the problem is likely your app code.

Comment: Back to the drawing board :( :(

Comment: Have you overridden some admin templates? Or maybe the login/registration templates? The files should be in `project/templates/admin` or `project/templates/registration/`. Just grep for `{% load .* from future %}` and remove those lines.

Comment: It's also possible that you are using a 3rd party package that needs to be upgraded but @HåkenLid has the most likely correct response.

Comment: Thanks everyone for helping.  The GREP comment help solve it very quickly.